# Create table using Go-Gorp fails to set column details

Tags: mysql, go, gorp

Trying to create the table using Gorp-Go ORM package. Was able to successfully create the table in MySql but failed to attach column details.

```
type Data struct {
    id int `db:"pid"`
    name string `db:",size:50"`
}
```

Gorp hook

```
Dbm.AddTableWithName(Data{}, "data_test").SetKeys(true, "id")
Dbm.CreateTablesIfNotExists()
```

Dbm is pointer to *gorp.DbMap*. The resultant table has *pid* and *,size:50* has name. Have tried with

```
   type Data struct {
        id int `db:"pid"`
        name string `db:"name:xyz,size:50"`
    }
```

Still the resultant column name is *"name:xyz,size:50"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp/issues/287#issuecomment-138815578), the size feature is still available in only dev branch.
You can achieve this by explicitly setting maxsize though. Example:

```
dt := Dbm.AddTableWithName(Data{}, "data_test").SetKeys(true, "id")
dt.ColMap("xyz").SetMaxSize(50)
Dbm.CreateTablesIfNotExists()
....
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the column name doesn't require "name"

Try `db:"xyz,size:50"`